# How to properly host Blazor WebAssembly App for Static Hosting -- including web.config

Tags: firebase, blazor, firebase-hosting, webassembly

I'm testing out Blazor WebAssembly and I'm hung up on one detail of deployment. I'm using the VS 2019 sample app, and deploying it to Firebase Hosting. It works, for the most part, but I can't figure out how the auto-generated web.config file should fit in.

When I publish the app to a local folder (call it `dist`), the contents are one file (`web.config`) and one `wwwroot` subfolder (where everything else goes, including `index.html`). If I deploy the entire `dist` folder, as expected the website cannot load on the internet because there is no `index.html` in the root. Conversely, if I deploy just the `wwwroot` folder, it can be loaded via the internet, but since the `web.config` file is missing, I get some issues with pages loading. I'm assuming that's because the rewrites contained within `web.config` are missing.

So my ultimate question is, when hosting in a non-IIS environment like Firebase, where or how does the `web.config` file, or its contents integrate?

Comment: web.config is used by IIS only, you don't need a web.config on static server ! If you have issues on page loading it's not because of web.config

Comment: So maybe it's just that Blazor WASM and Firebase don't play well together.